# Does not search for the same values in table

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, signals

I have the following problem. I am trying to sample a given signal and when I loop through the points of the signal every so often the values take 0 even though there are such values in the array. With other functions there is the same loop and it works fine.

```
for sample in samples:
    tmp_a_index = np.where(sygnal.time_samples == sample)[0][0]if sample in sygnal.time_samples else None
    tmp_a = sygnal.data[tmp_a_index] if tmp_a_index is not None else 0
    data.append(tmp_a)
```

Generates samples from a specified interval:

```
samples = np.arange(0, end_time, period)
```

Results:

```
[0.  0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.  1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2.  2.2 2.4 2.6 2.8 3.  3.2 3.4
3.6 3.8 4.  4.2 4.4 4.6 4.8 5.  5.2 5.4 5.6 5.8 6.  6.2 6.4 6.6 6.8 7.
7.2 7.4 7.6 7.8 8.  8.2 8.4 8.6 8.8 9.  9.2 9.4 9.6 9.8]
```

And data from signal:

```
[0.   0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.1  0.11 0.12 0.13
0.14 0.15 0.16 0.17 0.18 0.19 0.2  0.21 0.22 0.23 0.24 0.25 0.26 0.27
0.28 0.29 0.3  0.31 0.32 0.33 0.34 0.35 0.36 0.37 0.38 0.39 0.4  0.41
(...)
9.66 9.67 9.68 9.69 9.7  9.71 9.72 9.73 9.74 9.75 9.76 9.77 9.78 9.79
9.8  9.81 9.82 9.83 9.84 9.85 9.86 9.87 9.88 9.89 9.9  9.91 9.92 9.93
9.94 9.95 9.96 9.97 9.98 9.99]
```

Chart:

[image]

I would like to eliminate those dots at the 0 value.

Comment: If my answer works for you, I'd appreciate you accepting the answer for everyone who stumbles on it to know that it works. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

Just index your array not to include the values you don't want (e.g., `0`)

You can do it in the following way:

```
a = np.array([0., 1., 2., 0., 1., 5., 0.])
a[np.argwhere(a > 0.)].flatten()
```

```
OUT: array([1., 2., 1., 5.])
```

Cheers